# Edit Resharper Intellisense suggestions

Tags: resharper, intellisense

I am using Resharper 6.1 in combination with VS 2008 and have the Resharper Intellisense enabled. It's working great, but some intellisense suggestions are driving me insane:

- '_' always suggests '_Appdomain'. Most of the time I just want the
  underscore so I have to escape the suggestion every time.
- When calling a method where the variable I want to pass has the same name as the
  parameter, the first suggestion is always the parameter. Eg:

  ```
  Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim someVar As String
    Dim result = DoSomethingElse(someVar :=)    '<--this
  End Sub

  Public Sub DoSomethingElse(someVar As String) 
     'stuff
  End Sub
  ```

I've tried to find where I can remove this or change the suggestion sequence, but no luck.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have '_AppDomain' pre-selected in the completion list prior to pressing Enter. In this situation you can either:

1. Explicitly close IntelliSense window with Esc before pressing Enter
2. Change the autopopup option to 'Display but do not preselect' for 'Letter and digits' context under ReSharper | Options | IntelliSense | Autopopup | VB.NET

Comment: Related topic on R#'s forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/436424;jsessionid=77042C4DA64F68695CDF625E023E7AC6?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

Resharper 6.1 added a new feature to control the way the intellisense autopopups act. Go to ReSharper->Options->Environment->IntelliSense->Autopopup and change the settings to "Display but do not preselect".

[image]

Note: this screen shot is for the C# settings, I just noticed your code example is in VB, I think there may be similar settings for VB too.